# How is PHP object called that has colons and brackets?

Tags: php

Advanced Custom Fields, other Wordpress plugins and PHP libraries save data in the following format:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:23:"A";i:1;s:23:"B";i:2;s:32:"C";}
```

How is this object called and were can I find more information on it? I already tried `array`, `dictionary`, `list` and `tuple`, but could not find anything that looked similar.

Comment: I could not find the answer you provided with my question. When searching for colon, brackets and PHP in either Google or SO, I cannot find it.

Comment: do  you speak about json ?

Comment: it's a [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize)'d string. it's NOT an object or anything. it's just a string that can BECOME an object/array/whatever.

Comment: @xNeyte No, this is not JSON. It is a serialized string, as mentioned in the linked answer.